# Can't Debug Web API called from MS Access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-access, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API (.Net MVC) that's being called from an MS Access VBA Module, like so:

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://ourwebserver/api/run", False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objHTTP.send (body) 'body is a string containing the parameters to be used
Debug.Print objHTTP.Status
Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText
```

Well, I need to be able to debug the actual api.  So, I have the project all loaded on my local machine, but I'm not sure how to actually debug the code.

What I've tried so far is to run the project, set a breakpoint at the top of the controller, then change the `objHTTP.Open` command to point to the localhost entry that's created:

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://localhost:54321/api/run", False
```

as well as:

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://localhost:54321/", False
```

...but, in both cases, the breakpoint is never hit.  It fails with `Status = 500`.

I've also tried attaching to debugger... but I don't know what to attach it to.  There's no w3wp.exe in the list.  I've tried to attach it to MSACCESS.exe and Chrome, but I'm just having no success.  When I attach to MSACCESS.exe, I get an error about not being able to establish a connection.

So essentially, I'm trying to figure out how to tell my VBA process to call my local API code so's I can debug it.  I'm having a hard time figuring out the magic words to make this happen.

**Edit:** For the record, when I try to run the project (F5 from VS), I get the following RTE in my browser:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its
>   dependencies. An API call exited abnormally. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800300FA (STG_E_ABNORMALAPIEXIT))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figgered it out!  I had run this solution before on my local machine, but had forgotten the sorcery required to get it to work.  Basically, this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its
>   dependencies. An API call exited abnormally. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800300FA (STG_E_ABNORMALAPIEXIT))

...was the result of `Identity Impersonate` being `true` in my web.config file.  So, we do this:

```
<identity impersonate="false" userName="dom\UserName" password="#########"/>
```

Then, I was able to F5 into my web app with no errors, and call the API with this code in VBA:

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://localhost:54321/api/run", False
```

I can now call the API from Access, hit breakpoints and step through!